# Order by Custom Field date not recognized

Tags: custom-field, order

Ok, so I have this custom field `wpcf-evento-data-inicio1` generated with the (great) Types plugin.
This is how it stores on db:
 `1372896000`
OK, so I want to order by this value. I'm doing it by url args, and i can't spot what is wrong... I'm currently doing like this:

```
mysyte.com/?post_type=evento&order=desc&orderby=meta_value_num&meta_key=wpcf-evento-data-inicio1
```

I have also tried with meta_value instead of meta_value_num

```
mysyte.com/?post_type=evento&order=desc&orderby=meta_value&meta_key=wpcf-evento-data-inicio1
```

it outputs like this order:

1. 1372896000
2. 1371600000
3. 1372204800

I just cannot see what is wrong, any ideas? Thank you so much.

*(edit: Pls note that this is a archive template (archive-evento.php)*

Comment: I just noticed you first wrote wpcf-evento-data-incio1 and then use wpcf-evento-data-inicio1

Comment: @birgire the first one was a typo. eddited. the one in url is right (double checked)

Comment: @birgire any ideas? thanks for spotting the error :)

Comment: I'm not sure you can order by meta this way, you can check out public query vars http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get a `meta_key` parameter to pass through a `GET` string at all. Many other parameters that I tested do pass through, though I did not do an exhaustive test, but `meta_key` does not.

If you want to verify that just add the following to the top of your `header.php` and inspect the query.

```
echo '<pre>'; 
var_dump($wp_query); die;
echo '</pre>';
```

I have never tried to pass that parameter before now but [checking the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars) (thanks @birgire), I see that `meta_key` is listed as a "Private" variable. You cannot pass private variables through an URL, even if the parameters are valid if passed directly to `WP_Query` via hard-coded PHP.

What you are attempting, seems to be intentionally not allowed. You can only modify the query via an URL using the parameters listed as "Public". Other parameters are ignored, as you can see by inspecting the query as above.

That aside, when I see "ordering" problems like that the first thing I suspect are sticky posts. If you were using `WP_Query` directly I'd suggest that you add `&ignore_sticky_posts=true` but I can't get *that* to pass through `GET` either.

However, if you really must, you should be able to force this through with a filter on `pre_get_posts`.

```
function order_by_meta($qry) {
  if (isset($_GET['meta_key']) && $_GET['meta_key'] == 'wpcf-evento-data-inicio1') {
    $qry->set('meta_key','wpcf-evento-data-inicio1');
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','order_by_meta');
```

Comment: I really appreciate your time and effor to help me on this. I checked http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query @ "Order & Orderby Parameters" where 'meta_value' and meta_value_num' are possible arguments, but i can't realize what's wrong. Oh, thats a archive template btw....

Comment: oh, I see now "Private query vars cannot be used in the URL,"

Comment: Yes, with `WP_Query` they are valid parameters, but they are _not_ ___public___ and so cannot be passed through an URL like you are apparently trying to do.

Comment: if you could pls edit your awnser with this info i will select it as awnser, to help other users with this same problem

Comment: My answer already states that `meta_key` is a "Private" variable.

Comment: oh, I see now, thank you very much for your help, and sorry to disturb with a silly question. In my defense, I say that i read this part of the codex before, but didn't see that.

Comment: It is not a silly question, and the answer is not immediately obvious.

Comment: I am very thankfulll for your help, @s_ha_dum, but i am triyng to solve the main problem of sorting the posts by those meta_values, and i am really really stuck at this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103669/change-loop-order-via-form-or-link-jquery-not-url

Comment: @user1576978 : see the edit