# Change loop order via form or link (jquery, not URL)

Tags: theme-development, custom-field, loop, customization

I would like to change the loop order via a link or form input, but it can`t load via URL, because i need to orderby=meta-value and this cannot be done via url args (acording the codex) , only like this:

```
<?php $argsvs = array( 
                    'post_type' => 'evento', 
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'meta_key' => 'wpcf-evento-data-inicio1',
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                    'order'=>'DESC' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $argsvs );
?>
```

How would I let the user change the above args to orderby another custom field? ex:

```
                        'meta_key' => 'wpcf-evento-data-inicio2',
                        'orderby' => 'meta_value'
```

If it was order by title or something like this, i could do it via URL like `?post_type=evento&orderby=title&order=ASC`, but for a `meta_key` and `orderby=>'meta_value'` args, this can't be done via URL

Comment: Just edited my answer to your other question and basically answered this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/103370/21376

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why *not* do it via URL parameter? You said you can't because Codex told you not to. But if you want to anyway, you could use a GET parameter:

```
// http://example.com/page-slug/?direction=DESC
if($_GET['direction'] == 'DESC'){
    $order = 'DESC';
} else {
    $order = 'ASC';
}

$args = array(
    ...
    ...
    'order' => $order,
);
```

Comment: Codex doesn't say you shouldn't do this, I guess (at least I don't remember it does). It only says that there is no built in option to do this.

Comment: Only referencing OP's statement
> and this cannot be done via url args (acording the codex)

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars 'Private query vars cannot be used in the URL, although WordPress will accept a query string with private query vars, the values will not be passed into the query and should be placed directly into the query.' :( that was the main problem. Great awnser btw, is there any security issues related? like sql injection or something

Comment: Well, not really in this example. Consider what may be passed on that variable `direction`. We're not blindly accepting any value. We are looking for one specific value and then changing a different variable based on that. Much different than "if something is there, use it no matter what" - get it?